# show a div based on a conditional ajax result in php form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a `PHP` form`looks like this

```
<form>
    <div id="inid">
        National ID: <input type="text" id="individual_nid" oninput="getIndividualName(this.value)" />
    </div>
    <hr />
    name: <div id="individual_name_fetch"></div>
    <hr />
    <div id="other_inputs fields" style="display: none;">
        more inputs fields...
    </div>
</form>
```

In my `PHP` form I have an input `textbox` where the user inserts a number

```
<input id="individual_nid" oninput="getIndividualName(this.value)" />
```

this `textbox` fires **on the fly** the following `ajax` function

```
function getIndividualName(val)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"get_individual_name.php",
        data: 'individual_nid='+val,
        success: function(data){

            $("#individual_name_fetch").html(data);

        }
    });
}
```

in this function, I pass the user's input to the `get_individual_name.php` page.

in the `get_individual_name.php` page, I have a `PHP` script that searches for the inserted number in the database and gets the corresponding individual name and fetches it to the `id="individual_name_fetch"` div.

the `PHP` script in the `get_individual_name.php` page looks like this:

```
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE national_id = '".$_POST['individual_nid']."' ");
if(mysqli_num_rows($q) == 1)
{
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
        echo $individual_name = $r['individual_name'];
    }
}
else
{
    echo $individual_name = 'Not in db';
}
```

**up to here everything is fine**

What I need to do now...

If the searched user founded in the db `(mysqli_num_rows($q) == 1)` then I want to display the other inputs div `id="other_inputs fields"` in the form.  and if not, then the `other_inputs fields` div hides again

How can I accomplish this?

**please be aware that the `ajax` function and the `PHP` script run on the fly**

---

***NOTE & UPDATE***
the script's output will be `HTML` code, for example

1. if the result found the output will be:

`<span style="color: green;"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw fa-lg"></i> <?=$individual_name;?></span>`

OR

2. in case no result found:

`<span style="color: red;"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw fa-lg"></i> No user found.</span>`

**What** I am thinking about is to assign a variable e.g. `$show_extra_fields = true` or `$show_extra_fields = false` and pass it back to the ajax function and from there I check the value of the $show_extra_fields variable and based on the value I show/hide the other fields div.

is this possible?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you, and yes I know that but this is the shortest code just to make clear what I have and what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you're asking you would add show and hide functions to the AJAX callback:

```
function getIndividualName(val)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"get_individual_name.php",
        data: 'individual_nid='+val,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

            $("#individual_name_fetch").html(data);
            if(data[0] != 'Not in db') {
               $('#other_inputs').show();
            } else {
               $('#other_inputs').hide();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements. ID's must not have spaces in them.

---

EDIT: Return JSON with PHP (**CAUTION:** [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!)

```
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE national_id = '".$_POST['individual_nid']."' ");
$json = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($q) == 1)
{
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
        $json[] = $r['individual_name'];
    }
}
else
{
    $json[] = 'Not in db';
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: in the script there is always an output, this output is an `HTML` code,  so in this case the `other_inputs` div will always appear

Comment: Then you may want to change the output to JSON and `json_encode()` the results. When you receive, you can test if a particular JSON variable is empty.

Comment: how can I do that? would you please put an example.  also Kindly check the information I added in my post.

Comment: @SULTAN I have made changes to your PHP code and to my jQuery code. Have a look. `data` should contain JSON

Comment: works.. I had to add a comma `,` at the end of `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Ah, my bad - I'll make the change too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `JavaScript`. Check the AJAX response then take an action depending on this response.

***Note:*** *Don't use spaces in the id in your html*

```
 success: function(data){

        $("#individual_name_fetch").html(data);
        if (data === 'Not in db') {
            document.getElementById('other_inputs_fields').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('other_inputs_fields').style.display = 'block';
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**The quick fix:** Don't produce any output in case there is no data. Just check for empty string in response.

```
    success: function(data) {
        if (data === "") {
            $('#other_inputs_fields').hide();
            $("#individual_name_fetch").html('No data available');
        } else {
            $('#other_inputs_fields').show();
            $("#individual_name_fetch").html(data);
        }
    }
```

**Long term solution:** This code still looks OK for student's assignments work or hobby project. But in all other cases, you better look for some WEB framework, like Symfony https://symfony.com/. Frameworks will help you to build your application in a more structured way, offering the best practices our of the box, including the security issues pointed out in comments.

Comment: I have to produce output in either cases

Comment: @SULTAN it's better to handle the messaging on the client side, updated examples above